# rails link_to maps to incorrect action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I have the following link set up

```
 %span{title: 'Publish/unpublish ALL', id: 'publish_all_link'}= link_to image_tag('lock.png'),
    toggle_publish_all_courses_path(@course.id),  remote: true, class: 'icon_link_button',
    'data-publish-all': "#{@course.public}", style: 'margin-top:-1.25em; background-color: #dfd'
```

When I mouse over it in the view I get what I expect:

```
foo.yuuk.dev/courses/toggle_publish_all.275
```

where `275` is the `id` of the current `course`.  But when I click on it,
it is routed to the wrong action:

```
D, [2015-08-16T08:40:42.134233 #58161] DEBUG -- : Action controller:
D, [2015-08-16T08:40:42.134869 #58161] DEBUG -- : params = {"action"=>"show", "controller"=>"courses", "id"=>"toggle_publish_all", "format"=>"275"}

D, [2015-08-16T08:40:42.135710 #58161] DEBUG -- : 'set_course' = "set_course"

D, [2015-08-16T08:40:42.135830 #58161] DEBUG -- : params = {"action"=>"show", "controller"=>"courses", "id"=>"toggle_publish_all", "format"=>"275"}
```

I've checked by routes - `rake routes | grep toggle_publish_all` yields

```
toggle_publish_all_courses GET    /courses/toggle_publish_all(.:format)  courses#toggle_publish_all
```

At this point I am stumped, blocked, etc.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am guessing you defined `toggle_publish_all` on the collection of courses, and you should have defined it as a member? (in your `routes.rb` file?)

Comment: It is defined in `routes.rb`:

`match '/courses/toggle_publish_all', to: 'courses#toggle_publish_all', :via => [:get]`

Comment: And you want to `toggle_publish_all` for a specific `course`? Right? And you also have the line `resources :courses` in your routes?

Answer (score 1):

Well, your `rake routes | grep toggle_publish_all` is clearly telling that it don't need any `id` at all. Look the url `/courses/toggle_publish_all`. But yes, if you want to pass any `id` with the url, you can make a query string for that. Like

```
link_to image_tag('lock.png'), 
        toggle_publish_all_courses_path(course_id: @course.id),..
```

What you saw in view, is also not a correct url, that was your first clue as it is wrong:

```
foo.yuuk.dev/courses/toggle_publish_all.275 # << see this
```

`.html`, `.js`, `.xml` etc are format, not `.275`. `link_to` allows you to pass the format also by passing like `format: :xml` like that.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much.  I still don't understand why the action and id that result are incorrect.  Here is the relevant line from `routes.rb`:

`match '/courses/toggle_publish_all', to: 'courses#toggle_publish_all', :via => [:get]`



But this is what I see when the link is clicked:

`params = {"action"=>"show", "controller"=>"courses", "id"=>"toggle_publish_all"}`

Comment: @JimCarlson Well, give another look the to `rake routes` output. see the url `/courses/toggle_publish_all(.:format)`. And your route helper don't need any argument, but you send it though. And it thought that it is a format you are sending, and set it there. But I don't know internally, how Rails does it. But it is obvious what I said.

Comment: I remove the argument and still get `params = {"action"=>"show", "controller"=>"courses", "id"=>"toggle_publish_all"}` --- that is, the action is incorrect, as is the id.

Comment: No idea. You may have same named url above some where. Otherwise what you are saying not making any sense.  :(

Comment: Interesting: I replaced "toggle" by "taggle" in routes.rb, the  link_to code, and the `toggle_publish_all` action in the Courses controller so as to rule out a name collision.  Alas, the behavior is the same.

Comment: @JimCarlson I am from India. So. tonight 11 PM, I will be free to see again, what is going on. I'll ping you if are around. Sounds good ?